# how to retrieve a list of domains hosted within a server

Tags: dns, server-administration

is there any way how to retrieve a list of domains hosted within a list of servers, f.e.
trying to find out how many other domains are hosted on the same server, and sharing common resources.

Preferable if this could be used under bash.

/Saulius

Answer (score 1):

You could query this [online service](http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/web-sites-on-web-server/) with `wget` or `curl`... but the form post's procedure looks a bit strange (look at the HTML source code before you use it).

Basically, this is looking-up an IP address in a database of domain names.

Comment: yes, i know these type of pages, however noticed that making more often requests, is not possible on them.
So i would prefer if there was a command for win/unix where i could get same information, similar to whois but getting more data.

Comment: I don't think that any 'Linux command' maintains a list of the worldwide domain name mappings os you can query it. So the only way to resolve your problem is to query such an online database.

Comment: But then again the question: how accurate is database? How does it renew resources?

Comment: Is there a list of all dns servers available, or at least the ones that provide possibility to query them?

As i don't have my own dns server, can't query my own, and unluckily don't know if anyone provides such service.

Comment: Every ISP provides one, and you also have the 'root' DNS servers. Google is your friend...

Comment: have checked google, good that there is a list of dns servers, but the question was how to check data from these servers, since using somebodys web page for this service is not efficient (not sure if it provide right information).